# Suitable db solution for high read rate

Tags: mongodb, redis, cassandra, memcached

I'll explain the use cases first.

High read rates (10000+ p/s), large dataset (lots of string codes(think promocodes)  looking for matchs, strings 10 - 20chars). Needs fast response time.

First thought was memcached. However to combat downtime if memcache goes down and starts repopulating the cache from a db like mysql.... i was thinking redis for auto repopulation of cache.

Is it true that redis does not persist to the hdd but instead a flush needs to be called for it to be backed up?

My hope is to use the code string as the key making lookup super quick. Value will be an id linking it to a db  record thats not needed by the api.

If i had to guess how many unique strings will be stored..... 10M + after a few months.

Iv also looked at Cassandra briefly and mongodb. Im thinking mongodb will not be enough due to it not storing entire list in memory?

Any insight into these systems is very helpful. Feel like im going around in circles.

The api is made in nodejs. (If it matters)

Answer (score 2):

10K/s is definitely not a high rate for a DB like Cassandra, according that your schema is done wisely. I bet it's the same for the others.
10M unique strings per months is peanuts for modern big data systems.

Whatever big data solution you retain, you will have to design the schema acording to the type of data and  operational needs.

IMO, the important ones are the following 2 questions :

**What you mean by "looking for matchs"?**

If you need indexing and search using substrings or regexps, you need a search engine: ElasticSearch or SOLR are great. Warning that E/S does replication and sharding but it's distribution model is still not 100% safe.

None of the systems you mentionned will provide the reactivity you seem to look for.

If you will query using static strings: a key-value store or column oriented database like Cassandra will be just the perfect fit. So all are good fit.

**What is a fast response time?**

With selecting the right technology and appropriate schemas all those systems will give you great response time under hundreds of milliseconds, but will it be fast enough for you?

REDIS and MemCached being in-memory will provide the faster responses.

And as a conclusion, the API being in node.js is irrelevant for the choice of your storage and indexing technology, unless you want to stick with Javascript for everything and MongoDB is more friendly for you, it can be a decent candidate depending on your search use cases.

Comment: thanks for the reply.
i need to search for whole strings as an example: "promocode1234"
my idea was to store this as the key in redis. this should tell me very quickly if this code exists. correct ? faster then possibly searching over a mysql table as an example. or are index columns in mysql stored in ram.. at any rate all i need is a true or false so i think a cache is faster.

Comment: i like redis over memcache purely because it can rebuild itself after a reboot.